# Regex inverse match for the whole line

Tags: regex

I've been trying to get this to work for an hour now but can't seem to do it, neither with the help of SO articles, or Regex101.com.

Have have some data and would like to return the lines that does not contain "/Common/http". Example data:

```
/Common/http and /Common/Another
/Common/http-mymon
/Common/another /Common/http
another line
```

The result I am looking for is:

```
/Common/http-mymon
another line
```

Any regex I use must match the whole line or it fails in the engine I use (https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath). This means that `http` would not work, but `.*http.*` would.

Hope this is fairly clear?

/Patrik

Comment: But `/Common/http-mymon` contains `/Common/http`, could you please clarify?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Indeed it does. But I only want to match that particular "word". I have a regex that I use to find the lines that does match it if that clarifies things `.*\/Common\/http(?!\S).*`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead regex like this:

```
^(?:.*?/Common/http-mymon|(?!.*/Common/http)).*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mA3cv2/1)

---

**Update:**

As per comment below OP wants to exclude `/Common/http` followed by `/` or a whitespace. In that case try this regex:

```
^(?!.*/Common/http(?:/|\s)).*$
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/mA3cv2/2)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, but http-mymon could be anything so while this might work in the particular data I provided it would not work for other combinations. I just want to exclude /Common/http, as a word.

Comment: @PatrikJ use ^(?:.*?/Common/http\S+|(?!.*/Common/http)).*$

Comment: @PatrikJ: In that case try: `^(?!.*/Common/http(?:/|\s)).*$`

Comment: Almost there, but it does not match `another line`

Comment: Of course it matches `another line`. Did you check 2nd demo?

Comment: @PatrikJ both demos use a multiline modifier, you might need to include that in your actual regex.

Comment: I don't know why it did not work in my regex101 instance (I was using m). When starting a new one it works. Did not work in Jayway, but that's my problem to solve, not yours. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can go with the following regex

```
^(?!.*\/Common\/http(?:\s))(.*?)$
```

This one is checking for no `/Common/http` in front before space using negative lookahead `(?!.*\/Common\/http(?:\s))`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Almost there, but "another line" was not matched with this combo.

Comment: @SabujHassan why do you use the lazy `.*?`? `.*` can never exceed `$` (except when used with a single line modifier, which clearly isn't the case here)

Comment: @SebastianProske you are perfectly alright about this.